# Mark eclipse editor as not dirty if there aren't any changes

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

I develop editor extended from org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor.
I use FileDocumentProvider for it

```
setDocumentProvider(new FileDocumentProvider());
```

Problem is that when I make some changes and undo them all, my editor is still marked as dirty.
How to prevent it?

I.e. I want to set dirty flag as false when I undo all changes. 
Look like I need somehow to override isDirty method, but how to do it?

Regards,
Vladimir

Answer (score 0):

In `AbstractTextEditor` following code resides:

```java
    @Override
    public boolean isDirty() {
        IDocumentProvider p= getDocumentProvider();
        return p == null ? false : p.canSaveDocument(getEditorInput());
    }
```

and in `AbstractDocumentProvider` which is inherited by your document provider:

```java
    @Override
    public boolean canSaveDocument(Object element) {

        if (element == null)
            return false;

        ElementInfo info= fElementInfoMap.get(element);
        return (info != null ? info.fCanBeSaved : false);
    }
```

There exist a method `resetDocument` inside `AbstractDocumentProvider` which does reset the dirty state - or you could use `fireElementDirtyStateChanged` method.

In both methods you must use the editor input as parameter.